# Provider clears Text in Textfield after a function is called

Tags: flutter, provider

I am using `provider` to show if there is an error in `textfield`.

if the text in `textfield` is empty then it shows `'error'` as `errorText` else it will show nothing,

Here's my code:

```
  class TextFieldPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<TextFieldProvider__>(context);
    TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Consumer<TextFieldProvider__>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(errorText: value.errorText),
          );
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.text == "") {
              provider.changeErrorText('error');
            } else {
              provider.changeErrorText('');
            }
          },
          child: Text("press"))
    ]));
  }
}
```

```
class TextFieldProvider__ extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _errorText = '';

  String get errorText => _errorText;

  changeErrorText(String text) {
    _errorText = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The problem is when I click the button it calls `ChangeErrorText()`  and removes the text in TextField.
How do I avoid it?

Comment: Where did you declare `_controller` in `build` or in `State<Widget>`?

Comment: @alex_sunder_singh  I have done it in my code, it is just a snippet not the full code

Comment: Add full code, I may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to set `listen: false` while creating an instance of provider.

It should be:

```
final provider = Provider.of<TextFieldProvider__>(context,listen: false);
```

Not This:

```
final provider = Provider.of<TextFieldProvider__>(context);
```

this was rebuilding the widget and text in TextField was been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `_controller`

> incorrect

```
class Class {

Widget build..{
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController()
 return ...
}
```

> correct

```
class Class {
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController()

Widget build..{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditFieldPage` should be as `StatefulWidget` and `_controller` should be  as property of `_TextFieldPageState`

```dart
class TextFieldPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFieldPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFieldPage> createState() => _TextFieldPageState();
}

class _TextFieldPageState extends State<TextFieldPage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<TextFieldProvider__>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Consumer<TextFieldProvider__>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(errorText: value.errorText),
          );
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.text == "") {
              provider.changeErrorText('error');
            } else {
              provider.changeErrorText('');
            }
          },
          child: Text("press"))
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you For your answer, I am using provider to avoid building the widget every time I press the Button, But This code will rebuild the widget everytime the Button is pressed.

Comment: Flutter rebuilds the widget for every keyboard visible and dismissal.